# Powershell: Which route/ISP is currently active?

Tags: powershell, routes

In my router there is a fallback setting which routes all traffic via mobile data if jitter of my cable isp is to high. How can i periodically check with powershell which isp (which route) is currently active?

Thanks

I get the next hops via pathping, but i'm not able to extract the output. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Would a simple "what's my ip" check work? Presumably the different ISP routes will present on different IP ranges (although maybe too many distinct ranges to useful?), but something like ```Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.ipify.org/"``` would potentially give you a pointer. Failing that, does your router have an API you can query to pull the current status (knowing the make / model would hel)?

Comment: No, theres unfortunatly no API at the router. Your solution works great if all traffic is routed in the same way. In my case the script should run on the PBX which have special routing settings. So, die SIP traffic could be routed via mobile and all other traffic is routed via cable.

Comment: Could you run the script on a *client* instead that sends traffic via the SIP route? Or configure the network settings somehow for whatever session is hosting PowerShell on the router to use the SIP route (assuming it isn't already - but if you're using ```pathping``` to test the active route it's presumably already using the SIP / mobile route otherwise the output would always show the cabled route)?

Comment: Read following : https://www.ringcentral.com/us/en/blog/what-is-jitter/